# how can I remove write access from a file?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, permissions, filesystems

I have a program, (logger lite -vernier) which has a configuration file, that I use to set up scientific experiments. the [configFile](http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/aaa/Default.gmbl)

when I run logger lite, the software changes the config file, and thus all my future experiments involve me having to make repetitious steps I do not want to make every time I set up a new experiment. I verified this, using the windows command `FC file1 Default` which show the files are the same prior to running an experiment, compared to after, regardless of whether I choose to save the file or not.

So then I right clicked on the file, and set the permissions, to read only. so I thought. I unchecked the boxes for write and modify, but when I ran the config file again, it was still modified.

So then I tried setting a "DENY" for Write, and Modify. When I do this, it selects read and write as well. See photos:

How can I disable writing and modifying, while allowing reading?

This is a windows 8.1 PC, and "public" is a standard, (not admin) user.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is normal.  "Modify" includes sub-permissions that are the same sub-permissions that make up "Read" and "Read/Execute", so when you select "Modify" to enable it, the "Read" and "Read/Execute" permissions are also enabled (since all of their sub-permissions have been set when you set Modify).

You can use a more granular approach, and assign the sub-permissions directly:

- Close the current permission editing dialog, and go back a window, to the Properties window.
- Choose "Advanced" instead of "Edit".
- Click "Change Permissions..."
- Select the user you want to modify.
- Click "Edit..."
- Add the "Deny" to the "Create Files/Write Data", "Create Folders/append data", "Write Attributes", "Write Extended Attributes", "Delete", "Change Permissions" and "Take Ownership".

You may want to peruse and test other permissions offered in there, to get them exactly how you'd like. :)